# Blomberg Bottom Freezer Constantly Leaking Water

Tags: leak, refrigerator

I have a 5yo fridge with a bottom freezer that accumulates ice on top of the condensate drain port. This causes the condensate to accumulate, freeze and sometimes drain onto the floor.

I have the exact same fridge and the exact same problem as the person in the video link below. I tried his solution of cutting back the drain valve, but it did not help.

I called the manufacturer and, without surprise, they were of no help. I'm allegedly the "only person with the problem"

Any idea what could be causing this?

https://youtu.be/u4UAlnFGrf0

Comment: Are you sure nothing's in the tube blocking it?

Comment: Yes, this is my 3rd time disassembling the freezer to clear the ice (I clear it just like in the video) and I never find a clog in the tube.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to condensation from air infiltration.

- Check that the refrigerator is level, or *very* slightly tilted back so that the doors swing shut on their own.
- Check *all* door gaskets, i.e. they should be clean, flexible and seal completely on the entire perimeter.
- Check that doors close *completely*. Adjust food contents, door hinges and anything else that might interfere with complete closure.
- Also, avoid putting open containers with hot food in the refrigerator, or anything else that might evaporate water.
- Avoid "browsing" the contents; leave the doors closed as much as possible.

Also, to make it easier for water to drain, reduce surface tension by putting a *single drop* of dish or HE laundry detergent, perhaps once per month, where the water accumulates by the drain hole.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've considered these and found no issues with the gasket. To top it all off, the ice accumulated while I was away from home over the past 3 months and the fridge/freezer was basically cleaned out and never opened.  I could try the soap suggestion, but it would mean I need to disassemble the freezer back wall every month. Surely there is another option.. that water should just drain away no?